# Why is my #hello not showing up?

Tags: html, css

This div below is not showing up at all.. 
All I'm trying to do is make a happy face...

```
<div>
  <div id="bin">
    <div id="inner-bin"></div>
    <div id="inner-bin_2"></div>
    <div id="hello"></div>
  </div>
</div>

#bin{
  border-radius:100%; 
  margin:40px;
  position:relative; 
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:#013249
}

#inner-bin{
  height:120px;
  width:120px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:108px;
  border-radius:100%;  
  background-color:#58A3C8;}

#inner-bin_2{
  height:120px;
  width:120px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:280px;
  border-radius:100%;  
  background-color:#58A3C8;}
}
```

This div below is not showing up at all.. 
All I'm trying to do is make a happy face...

```
#hello{
  height:120px;
  width:10px;
  position:absolute;
  left:108px;
  border-radius:100%;  
  background-color:#58A3C8;
}
```

Comment: For one your CSS is not in a `<style>` tag.  For 2 you have too many `}` at the end there.  For III, it works on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mh6fm/) (comment out `<div id="hello"></div>` and the oval goes away)

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nynjr/

Comment: you have an extra right curly bracket in your styles...

Comment: Try to use proper formatting on your code and it it makes it much easier to debug.  As already said here a few times.  #inner-bin_2 has and extra } after it.  It is much easier to see when you format it to look nice.

Comment: You know, syntax errors happen to everyone. At least this guy posted code, so I'm going to +1 him for that. I think I can at least give him the benefit of the doubt that he was putting his CSS in a `<style>` block, and not give him the impression we're all a bunch of needlessly nitpicky yutzes that will overblow a n00b's first attempts to ask for help on SO.

Comment: check link http://jsfiddle.net/CwrZd/

Comment: That being said, @Cory Kelly, oftentimes it's also easier to use a text editor that's built for coding and highlights missing or extra closing braces. Another thing I find that works nicely is first pasting my code into jsFiddle, highlighting the block, and hitting tab once. Highlight it again, copy it, and then paste it into the StackOverflow editor, and it should block-indent properly and make it easier to read for you and others. Saves the effort of having to manually hit four spaces for each line, and you get your indentation from jsFiddle to boot. Good luck!

Comment: [This smiley face](http://jsfiddle.net/mh6fm/1/) is more fun anyway :P

Comment: Why do we people style on IDs? I can't understand it. Use classes to style on, and scope with your IDs!

Comment: @kunalbhat : Considering he's drawing a smiley-face with CSS, I don't think a deep discussion on semantic class vs. ID is warranted, but from a purist perspective, each of the elements he's attached IDs to are uniquely positioned and unique entities, which is what ID is for in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra closing-brace, after your #inner-bin_2:

Comment: Thanks guys for the grace.. and feed back.